# Sens : « l'aller » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: sens, pronoms, verbes

> Je vous demande pardon, monsieur… pour s’en aller ? C’était le conservateur du musée de Vanne-en-Bresse. Ce pauvre homme, qui ne trouvait plus la sortie, l’allait quêtant de porte en porte. Successivement il avait pénétré :
> chez le commis d’ordre Guitare, au même moment où cet ingénieux employé rafistolait son soulier avec un morceau de ficelle  ;

Je ne trouve pas de trace de « l'aller » dans le TLFi. Il est évident que « l' » est la forme élidée de « le ». Qu'ajoute ce pronom ? Quelle variante de sens est ajoutée à « aller » en le faisant précéder du pronom ?

On trouve cet usage déjà au 19<sup>e</sup> ([Traité de l'amour de Dieu
saint François de Sales · 1882](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Trait%C3%A9_de_l_amour_de_Dieu/vYMQspqhoQAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22l%27allait%22&pg=PA176&printsec=frontcover)).

[image]

Comment: @Personne Bon, voilà l'avènement de l'ogni…

Comment: @Personne Pas de problème de théâtre non plus, et je n'ai pas parlé de typographie. Il n'est pas question de théatre, ni de personne qui parle vite ; d'ailleurs on trouve cela dans du texte d'énumération, où le théâtre n'a certainement pas sa place.

Comment: Une piste ? https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1950/02/08/les-archaismes-de-grammaire_2039753_1819218.html

Comment: Puisque tu es sûr que ce  « l' » est la forme élidée de « le » peux-tu compléter ta question en ajoutant quel nom ce pronom représente ? Je ne vois vraiment pas.  Je ne peux comprendre la phrase qu'en interprétant « l' » comme la forme élidée de « la » (mis pour sortie) mais visiblement je dois me tromper, je n'ai pas compris la phrase.

Comment: @None C'est justement là le problème, il ne représente rien. Il ne représente rien bien évidemment aussi dans la référence qui complète ma question. // Avez-vous un souvenir d'un tel usage ? Je n'ai jamais rien lu de tel, ce serait toujours « allait la quêtant ».

Comment: Dans la ref. de la question, pour moi (mais visiblement je me trompe) « l' » est mis pour la princesse,  COD mis avant le verbe.  Pour moi le fait que aller soit suivi du p. présent est accessoire, et quand il n'y a pas de p. présent pour moi ça ne change rien. Juste  à constater que quand on  a aller+p. présent le pronom COD se place avant aller et pas avant le pp. Même phénomène quand aller est suivi de l'infinitif comme  sont le même phénomène pour moi.  [Il l’allait voir](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/centenaire-de-la-naissance-du-marechal-foch-bruxelles) (Votre Souverain)

Comment: Aussi « _Aller_, Se mettoit autrefois avec le gerondif de tous les verbes. » ([Ac.1694](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A1A0142)).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*réponse concernant le texte de Courteline seulement*

Il est presque certain que le pronom n'est pas « le » mais  « la » ; on trouve au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle de nombreux cas où le pronom est placé avant le verbe. Il suffit de passer cette [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22l%27allait%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) en revue pour les découvrir.
Voici un  cas où « la » est utilisé.

- ([Voyage à travers l'Amérique du Sud de l'Océan Pacifique à ...1869](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Voyage_%C3%A0_travers_l_Am%C3%A9rique_du_Sud_de/_8qZ4HLbnvQC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22l%27allait%22&pg=PA387&printsec=frontcover)) Chargé d'une provision de bois , il rentrait au village et l'allait déposer au centre de la place

Très probablement, « l' » (« la ) est mis pour  « sortie ».

Comment: Ah  ?  Tiens ! Tu affirmais plus tôt qu'il ne représentait rien, laissant entendre que je me trompais.

Comment: @None Je ne laisse rien entendre, évidemment si j'ai raison alors vous n'avez pas vu juste, mais je pensais seulement à l'impression que ça me faisait, ça me semblait impossible. User Personne dans les commentaires nous parle bien de théâtre et de « il » ; maintenant on peut être un peu plus sûr qu'il n'était pas sur la bonne voie. Il faut croire en ce qu'on croit.

Comment: Je rappelle quand même [mon commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53360/sens-laller-messieurs-les-ronds-de-cuir-georges-courteline/53368?noredirect=1#comment112966_53360) où il est écrit « Je ne peux comprendre la phrase qu'en interprétant « l' » comme la forme élidée de « la » (mis pour sortie)  », écrit 58 min avant cette réponse et auquel tu avais répondu presque aussitôt : « C'est justement là le problème, il ne représente rien. ».

Comment: @None Je vois, j'ai dû négliger ça alors, mon erreur.

Comment: @None tu as raison, ce "l'" représente clairement la _sortie_ dont il est question just avant la virgule.

Comment: Que peut-on penser de quelqu'un qui pose des questions pour lesquelles il refuse les suggestions et réponses données et d'en reprendre le contenu pour s'accepter la réponse à sa propre question ?

Comment: @None Dans ces cas-là les points ne sont pas comptés, alors ça ne dérange personne. Oh, au fait, je ne vois pas ces suggestions dans les réponses.

Comment: Au temps pour moi pour les points. Pour rappel  commentaire 2023-07-12 13:50:04 et 14:41:11 et réponse de @Frank qui rappelle ce commentaire et écrit " le l' représente *la sortie*".  J'ai moinsssoyé parce que j'estime que la réponse acceptée devrait comporter une explication grammaticale, explication donnée en commentaire à la réponse de Frank, libre à lui ou un autre de l'inclure en élaborant si possible (je donnerai ma ref si je la retrouve).

Comment: @None est-ce que je peux reprendre ton commentaire tel quel dans ma réponse avec attribution?

Comment: @Frank Ce serait bien d'avoir une ref exacte. Mais tu peux reprendre ce que tu veux...

Comment: @None On peut l'ajouter si tu la retrouves?

Comment: @Frank Je ne sais pas si c'était celle-ci mais ça s'y trouve aussi, une référence à la grammaire de l'ancien français de Buridant. https://theses.hal.science/tel-00872100/file/LIERE.pdf Unité auxiliaire-auxilié et p. 63 la citation. Bon courage !!!! Si ça t'intéresse.

Comment: @None je me plonge... j'aime bien certains exemples: _Et chis emperes avoit letres seur lui escrites qui disoit que juroit que ja li Sarrasin n’aroient triuves de lui_ et autres :-)

Answer (score 2):

Dans *Ce pauvre homme, qui ne trouvait plus la sortie, **l’allait** quêtant de porte en porte*, le **l'** représente la *sortie* dont il est question juste avant la virgule, tout simplement. *Il allait quêtant la sortie*, ni plus, ni moins.

Note: je n'avais pas compris pendant un moment, mais au vu des commentaires de @None, tout cela me paraît maintenant très clair, et je ne vois pas d'autre possibilité.

Voici l'explication grammaticale fournie par @None:

> C'est un héritage de l'ordre des mots en ancien et moyen français qui a commencé à disparaitre à l'époque classique, mais encore possible, archaïsme pour Courteline. « Le pronom régime ne peut occuper la place précédant immédiatement l’inﬁnitif qu’à condition de s’appuyer sur un élément accentué placé avant lui. » (perdu la ref) Cet usage concerne les emplois d'aller (venir aussi il me semble) comme auxiliaires, devant un participe présent ou un infinitif.

Comment: C'est un héritage de l'ordre des mots en ancien et moyen français qui a commencé à disparaitre à l'époque classique, mais encore possible,  archaïsme pour Courteline. « le pronom régime ne peut occuper la place précédant immédiate
ment l’inﬁnitif qu’à condition de s’appuyer sur un élément accentué placé avant lui. » (perdu la ref) Concerne les emplois d'aller (venir aussi il me semble) comme auxiliaires (devant un p. présent/infinitif).

Comment: @None - En vrai, c'est assez _stylé_. Dommage qu'on n'utilise plus.